# Как сделать фон из вертикальных линий через linear-gradient?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Не могу разобраться с linear-gradient, как сделать подобный фон? Нужна серая линия шириной в 1px через каждые 160px, бесшовно на всю ширину и высоту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, примерно так, с толщиной линии можно поиграться третьим параметром linear-gradient (#fff 99.5%).

```css
.block {
  /* Решение */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 0%, #fff 99.5%, #ccc 0%);
  background-size: 160px 50%;
  /* Вспомогательный код */
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно!

Comment: а почему бы сразу в пикселях не задать толщину?)

Comment: Есть еще `repeating-linear-gradient()`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сказал интересную вещь, можете просто указывать толщину линии как вариант :)     ```background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 159px, #ccc 1px);```